# Request not passing req.body through to other service

Tags: node.js, express, api-gateway, npm-request

I have a Node.js API gateway that passes requests to my different services. It seems to pass the URL correctly (expected) but it is not passing `req.body` to my other services, in this case my auth service.

**Here is my route**

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  request.post(req.path, options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(body);
  });
});
```

**Here is my route in my auth service**

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body)

});
```

I am getting back `{}` as my response to the API gateway so it seems like my `req.body` is not being passed through to my auth service. I'm not sure the correct way to have it pass through the whole `req` object to the auth service while using the request package.

EDIT**

I think that I need to include `form: {key:'value'}},` somewhere in the request where I include `req.body` as part of the form data. Not sure how this would work since I already have the options included to set my base URL which is dynamic based off a setInterval elsewhere in my code.

```
options = {
    baseUrl : serviceURL
  }
```

Comment: Have you added body-parser?

Comment: @AdemolaAdegbuyi yes body-parser is added in with json and urlencoded in my `app.use`

Comment: @AdemolaAdegbuyi Looks like the issue is that req.body is not getting passed at all to my request I am sending using the NPM package `request`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's from your client. What do you use in sending the request, and have you tried using postman?

Comment: @AdemolaAdegbuyi I am using postman yes